# How to set BindingContext of multiple pages to the same ViewModel in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and I'd like to create a cross-platform app using MVVM pattern and XAML. In my forms project (pcl) I'd like to set the **BindingContext** of my **MainPage** and also multiple pages in the future to the same ViewModel. Is this possible? Let me show what I'm talking about. Below is a code snippet from an earlier **WPF** project of mine (*App.xaml.cs*):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private MainWindow _MainWindow;
    private MyViewModel _ViewModel;

    public App()
    {
        _ViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        _ViewModel.SomeEvent += new System.EventHandler(ViewModel_SomeEvent);
    }
}



protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    _MainWindow = new MainWindow();
    _MainWindow.DataContext = _ViewModel;
    _MainWindow.Show();         
}

private void ViewModel_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do something
}
```

The contents of the ViewModel are not important. With this structure I was able to set the same `_ViewModel` object as the **DataContext** of multiple windows. Is there an equivalent to this in Xamarin.Forms?

Here is a simple code from my pcl project (*App.cs*):

```
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage ()
    {   
        return new MainPage();
    }
}
```

And the code from *MainPage.xaml.cs*:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{   
    public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel ();
    }
}
```

I understand this is a proper way to set the **BindingContext** of a page but I'm wondering if this will result in creating a new ViewModel object with default values every time I open `MainPage`. And also I don't understand how other pages will be able to use the same ViewModel object as `MainPage`. In my opinion the above **WPF** project code is logical and simple. One ViewModel object and that's it. Do I have to create different ViewModel classes to every page? That's just seems wrong to me.

So is there a way to somehow create one ViewModel object - maybe in *App.cs*? I doubt it. - somewhere to be used by every page I might want to add to the project later. I hope I've been clear and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly set the BindingContext of a page to an object that your application manages; the ViewModel does not have to be created (or even set) inside the constructor; that just happens to be what a lot of sample code does.

There are several approaches you can take for: a ViewModelLocator that creates a single ViewModel and exposes it to any view that uses that ViewModelLocator to wire up the binding context, a dependency injection container (like the SimpleIOC that MvvmLight provides) with the ViewModel registered as a singleton, manually setting it in a Page factory, and so on.

A simple example using a ViewModelLocator referenced in the ctor would be:

```
public static class ViewModelLocator
{
    private static MyViewModel _myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    public static MyViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _myViewModel;
        } 
    } 
}

...

public partial class MainView : ContentPage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.MainViewModel;
    }
}

...

public partial class SomeOtherView : ContentPage
{
    public SomeOtherView()
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.MainViewModel;
    }
}
```

You can also have it so that the _myViewModel member is set through a setter on the ViewModelLocator, pull it from an IOC container, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! This ViewModelLocator approach is awesome!

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty useful. You can even use the ViewModelLocator pattern to use  specific ViewModels for different conditions (like, say a "mock" ViewModel for debug builds).